# Why the characters in buffer cannot enter a while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, buffer, getchar

why there is no "*" in output?
the input is :
abcde[enter key]

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char ch;
    while ((ch=getchar( ))== 'e')
        printf(" * ");
    
    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering that the abcd'\n' will be stored in buffer when i click the enter key, and the **getchar()** will constantly read it until catch the char 'e' and print the "*"

Answer (score 0):

With input "abcde", there is no "*" printed because while loop reads character by character from standard input, while the read character is equal to character `'e'`. Once you enter a character different from `'e'` while loop breaks. As your input is "abcde" in first iteration of while loop variable `ch` becomes equal to `'a'` and condition `ch == 'e'` is equal to `false` and after that loop breaks. That while loop is same like this loop:

```
while (1){
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch != 'e') break;
    printf(" * ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter "abcd" what's the first value returned by getchar() and what happens to your loop?